# How many gigabases of DNA are there on earth?

Tags: genetics, dna, bioinformatics

The human genome is about 770 MB, the *C. elegans* genome is about 100 MB, the yeast *S. cerevisiae* is about 12 MB. Different other genomes have been sequenced: how many GB of genomic DNA we have now?

Let say we would like to make a Noah hard-disk ark: how much space would it take to represent the genomes of all known species on earth? There is a way to provide an estimate?

I'm also interested in the total biodiversity: for instance, if two species each have 1 GB genomes and have half of their DNA in common this would count as 1.5 GB.

Comment: I think this is an unanswerable question - there are a handful of species whose genomes have been sequenced, and many millions on the earth that remain completely uncharacterised!

Comment: The human genome has highly repetitive (“low complexity”) regions though, which means that it can be compressed much further. *This* is the real measure of biodiversity “size” since it measures the actual information content. And adding genome sizes is much more complex than you make it out, your 1.5 GB approximation isn’t very precise.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You have to choose between the most reductive representation of the genome and the fullest one.  I'm sure we'll have records of hundreds of millions of variants in the human genome alone by the end of the next decade.  There are proposals to move away from a single reference build for the human genome.  Not only storing the sequence itself, but annotation describing how the variants are used already blows the doors off of 770 MB.

Comment: @shigeta I don’t think this is relevant here. What Craig wants to measure is the combined information content of all genomes, and the information content is by definition the entropy which, again by definition, corresponds to the size of the data in its tightest (theoretically) possible representation.

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to understand.  Total information measures are convenient for bookkeeping, but considering the recent work that shows how frequently horizontal gene transfer occurs in bacteria, http://phys.org/news205389256.html, its probably true that you will never run out of bacterial genomes to add to the sequence database as @MarkSchltheiss is pointing out.  I'm definitely more of a pessimist w.r.t. the tractability a complete genomic sequence catalog.

Comment: Why is it more interesting to talk about megabytes, rather than megabases?

Comment: @nico Because people are used to thinking in bytes; they have a relative impression of how much "1GB of information space" can hold.

Comment: @Armatus: OK... although to me it makes much more sense to talk about megabases. Personally I don't have an impression of how much of a DNA sequence can be stored in 1Gb... also because it really depends on how you store it.

Comment: @nico: I suppose we like to convert things into units that we can relate to known quantities. E.g. I'm used to metres so I'd always rather convert inches and miles. I can't imagine how far "5 miles" is exactly. But I know that it's roughly 1:1.5 so about 7.5km which is about 3/4 the way to work which I cycle in about 25 minutes and so on. :)

Comment: If you want to represent all genetic information on Earth, you need to get all *individuals*, not all species. There is significant variation between two humans or two birch trees, so you can't just take a single sample per species and say 'got it!'.

Comment: What's with compression algorithms?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you simply take one order of insects, Coleoptera, there are just under 400,000 described species with estimates from 850,000 to 4,000,000 species total in just this order.  The number of primates is under 1,000.  If your assumption of say 10MB for all other primates would be accurate, just adding in the low end estimate of 850,000 at 10MB per 1000 we are quickly at 8,500GB which seems to be a factorial out of the GB range.

So, we have a broad estimate of non-bacterial of plants, animals etc. at say 8,700,000.

Jason Gans found in a 1 gram of soil survey approximatly 1,000,000 bacterial species.

**SO the total accounting for species number is totally impossible to estimate for anything at this time, let alone the genome**.

Even for something as "common" as a giraffe, there are up to 9 sub-species with genome differences within each subspecies.

So, once we get them all decribed, we can then work on the genome sequence for each and get you some answers!

Comment: Recent genetic work on the Giraffe now indicates multiple species of what were once thought to be sub-species, some of which are now viewed as endangered of extinction due to the low population numbers in some.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this paper](https://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=10.1371/journal.pbio.1002168) there is ~ $5.3 \times 10^{34}$ base pairs of DNA on earth. One base pair contains approximately 2 bits worth of information (4 possibilities). So that would be ~ $8.48 \times 10^{35}$ bytes of information.

or more than the total information in [all digital and analog](https://phys.org/news/2011-02-world-scientists-total-technological-capacity.html) technological storage media on earth combined.

Comment: I was mostly wondering about thy total information content in all dna on earth. This number is probably much higher than the total information content as many of those strands will be duplicates, but I upvoted your answer as this still provides a good upper bound and possibly some good places to start with other calculations. Thanks!

Comment: duplicate information is still information, most of the information in books or on digital media is duplicate as well. Any estimate you compare it to will contain a lot of  duplicate information. Alos the original paper lists the number in megabases, I converted for convenience.